# How to get positional coordinates (n×2) for a uniformly spaced array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, psychopy

I am trying to make an array of line elements (23×23 grid) using the [`ElementArrayStim`](http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/visual.html#psychopy.visual.ElementArrayStim) from PsychoPy.

For the `xys` parameter for positions of the line elements, I am trying to get the line elements positioned in a uniform manner (23×23 grid).

I have tried to get the positions of the elements by doing the following:

```
nx, ny = (23, 23)
xaxis = np.linspace(-220, 220, nx)
yaxis = np.linspace(-220, 220, ny)

yx = np.meshgrid(xaxis, yaxis)
```

The output I am receiving from that seems to be 2 separate arrays (I assume for x-axis coordinates and y-axis coordinates), but they seem to be listed in terms of each line.

However, PsychoPy only accepts n×2 inputs for the `xys parameter - and I am not sure how do I go about changing shape of the output so it is in the form of n×2.

Also, if the method I am using is incorrect/inefficient, what would be the best way to achieve the `xys` positional elements in a n×2 shape?

- by n×2, I mean two columns with 23 × 23 = 529 rows. The columns will be for the x and y coordinates respectively, and the 529 rows will be for each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close, just needed to create a 3D array of coordinates from `xaxis` and `yaxis` and then reshape that 3D array to get a 529 rows × 2 columns 2D array as required:

```
In [21]: xy = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(xaxis, yaxis)).reshape(-1, 2)

In [22]: xy
Out[22]: 
array([[-220, -220],
       [-200, -220],
       [-180, -220],
       ..., 
       [ 180,  220],
       [ 200,  220],
       [ 220,  220]])

In [23]: xy.shape
Out[23]: (529L, 2L)
```

Alternatively, you could have obtained the same result through the following approach:

```
xy = np.mgrid[-220:240:20, -220:240:20].T.reshape(-1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Tonechas. 
Using transpose (.T) wasn't as effective as the first suggestion you had - which works brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to loop over both axis, appending each element to the array as you go ?

```
fred=np.array([[],[]])
for column in xaxis:
    for row in yaxis:
        fred = np.append(fred, [[column], [row]], 1)

fred.shape
(2, 529)
```